# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient missing GetAwaiter

Tags: c#, async-await, portable-class-library

I have this error in visual studio. It is PCL I have added my solution and I am trying to use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient and not the one in System.net.http. I have a reference for "Windows" but gets the following error by the GetAsync call:

*'IAsyncOperationWithProgress' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperationWithProgress' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)*

"using System;" is in the top of the file. In many examples like the following I can see it should work but I must be missing something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(GetBaseUri());

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
                    return model;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're missing the `using` directives that provide the awaitable API.

Comment: I have another class in same project where it works, just using System.Net.Http in that case.

Comment: If you type `.GetAwaiter()` after the call to `GetAsync` on that class, what happens?